# orca server communication problem with large dataset

Tags: python, plotly, orca

I am using orca to export an image created with plotly. With small datasets there is no problem. But when I'm trying to plot very large dataset I get the following error:

```
ValueError: 
For some reason plotly.py was unable to communicate with the
local orca server process, even though the server process seems to be 
running.
```

This is my code:

```
fft = pd.DataFrame({'Amplitude':ampl}, index=freq)
fig2 = fft.iplot(kind = 'bar',  asFigure = True)
filename ='FFT.png'
fig2.write_image(filename, format='png')

fft.size = 384553
```

I am using plotly v4.1.0 and orca v1.5.1.

Creating the html is working too, but it needs a lot time to load in browser. So I thought the static export might be better.

Does anyone know, if orca isn't working for large datasets or has some kind of limitation in datasize?